# Custom Updatable ListView - Android Development

Tags: android, listview

As a goal for my first Android application to learn the Android SDK, I am trying to create a simple RSS viewer for a specific url. Disregarding the networking side of the goal, I am having trouble with getting a listView to display a custom layout.

What I'd like to do is have each row of a list view show one of two images(read or unread), followed by some text. I'm not really having a problem, it's more that there aren't any examples that I could find (I might be looking in the wrong place) that covered custom layouts depending on conditions in code.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that discusses the techniques involved. In a nutshell, you will need to extend your `Adapter` class (e.g., `ArrayAdapter`, `CursorAdapter`) and take direct control over the creation of rows, so you can apply your desired business logic.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! I'll read through it tomorrow.

Comment: +1  
Mark's "Fancy ListViews" also cover all of the ListView optimizations that Romain Guy highlighted during the I/O conference; it is a must read!