# How to make a row of ListView like this?

Tags: android, listview, layout

Sorry, this's my first time to ask a question here. So, I don't have the permission to upload the image to describe. Never Mind. What I would like to make is a row of ListView like this. The block on the left is an icon.

Much appreciated if you could feedback the correct XML tags. Thanks.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-------
|　　|　　　　　　　　　　some text　　　　　some text
|　　|　　　　　　　　　　some text　　　　　some text
-------
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Check this [CommonsWare's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962266/custom-updatable-listview-android-development/1962490#1962490) dont duplicate the question. first search for question if you didnt get answer then ask.

Comment: The image/icon on the left should be "rowspan", the text on the right is kind like a table which has four cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the past few hours, I've finally found the solution by myself. Hopefully, this could do some help to others. This is my first contribution to this forum.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60px">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="32px"
        android:layout_width="32px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20px" />
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="0px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="62px">
        <TableRow
            android:minHeight="30px">
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:minHeight="40px">
                <TextView
                    android:text="SOME TEXT"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:textSize="10pt"
                    android:width="150px"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:minHeight="40px"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="99999"
                    android:id="@+id/amount"
                    android:textSize="10pt"
                    android:paddingRight="20px"
                    android:minHeight="40px"
                    android:gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:width="108px" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:minHeight="20px">
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:text="SOME TEXT"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:width="150px"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                    android:minHeight="20px" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="some text"
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:paddingRight="20px"
                    android:minHeight="20px"
                    android:gravity="top|right"
                    android:width="108px" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is a little bit tricky by using the combination of RelativeLayout & TableLayout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Some text some text some text some text"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Some text some text some text some text"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No, this is not. But thanks, I will make it clearly in my question.